# Importing IOS SDK libraries to a Flutter Plugin

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

Summary:
I am building a Flutter Plugin to be used for multiple projects I am developing. I have no experience writing custom platform-specific code.

I am having trouble importing SDK library for IOS *.Framework and *-Resources.bundle to my plugin.

I've tried to the solution for in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978

Also, I've tried cleaning and re-building the app but with no success and tried cleaning and re-building the example app but with no success
and I receive the below error:

*.podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'plugin_name'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
end


Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name         = "plugin_name"
  spec.version      = "2.3.7"
  spec.summary      = "SDK"
  spec.homepage     = "https://hkhars.com"
  spec.author       = "Hussain Alkhars"
  spec.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  spec.source           = { :path => '.' }
  spec.ios.deployment_target  = '9.0'
  spec.preserve_paths = 'IOSFLUTTERSDK.framework'
  spec.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework IOSFLUTTERSDK' }
  spec.vendored_frameworks = 'IOSFLUTTERSDK.framework'
  spec.public_header_files = "IOSFLUTTERSDK.framework/Headers/*.h"
  spec.resource_bundle = { 'IOSFLUTTERSDK-Resources' => './*' }
end
```

Error when trying to build with `flutter build ios --no-codesign`

````
fatal error: 'plugin_name/PluginNamePlugin.h' file not found
    #import <plugin_name/PluginNamePlugin.h>```
````

Answer (score 2):

You've mangled your Podspec file. There should only be one section starting `Pod::Spec.new do |s|...`. If you want to try the approach in the linked Github issue, your Podspec file should look like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'plugin_name'
  s.version          = '0.0.1'
  s.summary          = 'A new flutter plugin project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new flutter plugin project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.preserve_paths = 'IOSFLUTTERSDK.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework IOSFLUTTERSDK' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'IOSFLUTTERSDK.framework'
  s.resource_bundle = { 'IOSFLUTTERSDK-Resources' => './*' }
end
```

However, I've tried this before with no success - I needed to link everything manually via Xcode by opening the project:

```
open example/ios/Runner.xcworksapce
```

Click on the "Runner" project at the top, and click on the "Build Phases" item on the right hand side (if "Build Phases" doesn't show, make sure the folder icon on the left is selected, and you've clicked the Runner *Target* in the middle panel, not the Runner Project).

[image]

Find the "Link Binary with Libraries" panel, and click the "+" button:

[image]

Select your .framework file and click "Done". Repeat the same under "Embed Frameworks".

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can do the same under "Copy Bundle Resources".